# how to display this kind of quotes « … »?

Tags: java, android

I m working on a application's project.
I want to display this quotation marks : « and » . But it shows numbers: 2131296435 and 2131296434.

Their value(« and ») are in an XML file:

```
<string name ="open_quote">«</string>
<string name ="close_quote">»</string>
```

and in my Java code I have something like this:

```
text.setText(R.string.open_quote+aStringValue+R.string.close_quote);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
<string name ="open_quote">\u00ab</string>
<string name ="close_quote">\u00bb</string>
```

You also should set the Text like this as every string value is saved as an Integer value into R.java:

```
text.setText(getString(R.string.open_quote) + "text" + getString(R.string.close_quote));
```

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#French)

Answer (score 2):

In your xml file,

try using the HTML entities: `&laquo;` for **«** and `&raquo;` for **»**
or the equivalent Unicode characters: `\u00ab` for **«** and `\u00bb` for **»**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
text.setText("\u003C\u003C); // for <<
```

Checkout this for unicodes

https://unicode-table.com/en/#003C

Comment: This is a bad suggestion. The spacing isn't correct, it takes two characters instead of one and you cannot search for the quote char in a text.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help.

I found out that the mistake didn't come from of my xml file , but in my java code

**It should be** :

```
getResources().getString(R.string.open_quote)
```

instead of :

```
R.string.open_quote
```

in xml, both works:

```
<string name ="open_quote">\u00ab</string>
<string name ="close_quote">\u00bb</string>
```

**OR**

```
<string name ="open_quote">«</string>
<string name ="close_quote">»</string>
```

So in my code, i have:
`text.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.open_quote)+aStringValue+getResources().getString(R.string.close_quote));`

Comment: `getString(R.string.open_quote)` and `getString(R.string.close_quote)` should also work for you.